# Where to get M2Crypto official documentation?

Tags: m2crypto

https://m2crypto.readthedocs.io/ is given as the documentation link from the official https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto link.

But when I open it and see there is no content about any module. Please check the below link.

https://m2crypto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/M2Crypto.html#x509-module

I thought that M2Crypto is deprecated but I still see that latest version is released in June 2021, so these people are showing their talent on common people it seems :) .

Please suggest where do I get the actual documentation for M2Crypto. I am not finding few methods on x509 module.

Answer (score 1):

There is none build automatically. There are plenty of documentation strings in the code, but if somebody fixes the build so that the documentation is automatically generated and uploaded to ReadTheDocs, I am all ears and eagerly awaiting a merge request.

Comment: Two years later I still see just titles, no content, at the ReadTheDocs site. This is super frustrating. I mean I can use the force and read the source too, but why?

Comment: Merge request at https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/ are welcome.